# Saved snapshot is only black square with plugin Cypress Image Snapshot

Tags: cypress, visual-testing, jest-image-snapshot

I tried to revive visual test in Cypress which run with help of plugin  Cypress Image Snapshot.

In the past this test during first run save image with desired element (image).
[desired_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEkKA.png)

But now test save during first run only black square:
[saved_black_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4l4xU.png)

This issue can be caused by upgrading the Cypress version (currently we use 9.5.1).

Does anyone had the same problem resp. can help me please?
Suggestions of good working free Cypress tools for visual testing are more than welcome.

Comment: Which Cypress version have you used prior?

Comment: "cypress": "6.4.0"